# Do uncalled functions cost performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if I for example wrote 100 function in a class or even without a class and only used one function in each time I call the class, Does these too many uncalled and unused functions influence the performance or count for something negative?

Comment: why are you worried about this?

Comment: @Chris_Rands i'm working on some real big class that would have too many functions (like100 or more) and i would only call (use) few of them like 5 of them in each time i call the class and i'm worried that writing too many would hurt the performance by any mean !

Comment: There's a one-time cost while compiling the script, but no overhead once it's running.

Comment: If you precompile the script, that cost is mitigated.

Comment: I wonder if you code design/structure an be improved. If you only call 5 functions in your class, maybe that deserves a new class or subclass (for readability/usability as much as performance)

Comment: @Barmar okay i got this, and i have one more question!, if i did convert the overall code into exe, will there be no cost at all ?

Comment: It's negligible.

Comment: @Chris_Rands i know it seems that i'm on wrong path to perform wut i'm doin but believe me it's the best easy way to do wut i'm on.

Comment: @Barmar thanks very much for ur help.

Comment: I would think the performance of the application would most likely depend upon the algorithm of the function(s) that does run, not the ones that don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *practically* no. Chunks of code that aren't executed don't influence the performance of the program. This is true for most / all programming languages - not just Python.

That being said, there are some scenarios where this is not accurate:

- If your program is very large, it may take a while to load. Once it loads, the execution time with or without the redundant code is the same, but there's a difference in load time.
- More code may impact memory organization, which in turn may impact the OS' ability to cache stuff in an effective manner. It's an indirect impact, and unless you know exactly what you're doing it's mostly theoretical.
- If you have a *very* large number of methods in a class, looking up a given method in a class' dictionary may take longer. The average cost of getting an item from a dict is O(1), but worst case can be O(N). You'll have to do *a lot* of optimization to (*maybe*) get to a point where you care about this.
- There might be some other obscure scenarios in which code size impacts performance - but again, it's more theory than practice.

Comment: Do you have any code, official docs, or other sources to support these claims? Not trying to get on you, I'm mostly just curious because in my brief search I didn't see much on how dead code is even handled in CPython, or other Python compilers. I'd think that the methods being embedded in a class wouldn't matter for Python, though maybe the .pyc generation is longer, but it's just speculation and I personally can't find much info.

Comment: As to the complexity of getting an item from a dict - see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: About the impact of caching on performance - there are many resources about this, but here's one: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24605-3_22

Comment: Longer load time - personal experience and common sense. Plus, if every 'import' statement consumes some amount of time, the more imports - the more time. And - reading stuff (python script) from disk requires IO, and IO takes time, So the more code, the more IO (at load time).

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren - see my previous three comments.